# R: Create a while loop to sum values below mean in a vector

Tags: r, loops, vector, while-loop

I could really use some help here, I want a while loop which will calculate the sum of all values below mean in a vector,  I also want to extract the amount of values within the sum,  the vector looks like this:

x <- log(1:200)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Based on your recent questions, I think that you will be better served by reading (completely!) a few basic manuals, rather than relying on SO for every little question that comes up. All of your questions thus far are really handily answered by any decent intro to R.

Comment: The point is that in R (most) operations are (or can be) vectorised, so you (usually) don't need to loop.  For a good clear explanation  I would recommend looking at one of Roger Peng's Coursera lectures on "R", on YouTube.  The one on subsetting should help you out:   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWbgqzsQJF0&list=PLjTlxb-wKvXPqyY3FZDO8GqIaWuEDy-Od&index=9

Answer (score 3):

Create logical vector indicating whether a value is below mean:

```
vec <- x < mean(x)
```

Sum all values below mean:

```
sum(x[vec])
```

Count values below mean:

```
sum(vec)
```